# How to get the text of img alt inside <a> tag

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have a url with the following html part

```
 <div class="shop cf">
 <a class="shop-logo js-shop-logo" href="/m/3870/GMobile">
 <noscript>

<img alt="GMobile" class="js-lazy" data-src="//a.scdn.gr/ds/shops/logos/3870/mid_20160920155600_71ff515d.jpeg" src="//a.scdn.gr/ds/shops/logos/3870/mid_20160920155600_71ff515d.jpeg" /> 
 </noscript>

<img alt="GMobile" class="js-lazy" data-src="//a.scdn.gr/ds/shops/logos/3870/mid_20160920155600_71ff515d.jpeg" src="//c.scdn.gr/assets/transparent-325472601571f31e1bf00674c368d335.gif" />

</a>
</div>
```

I want to get the first img alt inside the div class shop cf and I do

```
  Set seller = Doc.querySelectorAll("img")      
  wks.Cells(i, "D").Value = seller.getAttribute("alt").Content(0)
```

I get nothing what I forget to include?!?

Can I get it from

```
<noscript>
```

tag?

I tried the following as well

```
  Set seller = Doc.getElementsByClassName("js-lazy")

  wks.Cells(i, "D").Value = seller.getAttribute("alt")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use element with attribute selector

CSS:

```
img[alt]
```

VBA:

```
ie.document.querySelector("img[alt]")
```

You may need to add

```
ie.document.querySelector("img[alt]").getAttribute("alt")
```

To include the class use

```
ie.document.querySelector("img.js-lazy[alt]")
```

If more than one element then use querySelectorAll and index into returned nodeList e.g.

```
Set list = ie.document.querySelectorAll("img.js-lazy[alt]")
list.item(0).getAttribute('alt')
list.item(1).getAttribute('alt')
```

Comment: So I do Set seller = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("js-lazy") and seller .querySelector("img[alt]").getAttribute("alt")

Comment: No. Just ie.document.querySelector("img[alt]").getAttribute("alt") unless you need to limit to that class? If you want to add class then selector is img.js-lazy[alt]

Answer (score 0):

have you try this way?

```
 let lazy1 = document.querySelectorAll(".js-lazy")[0]
 let lazyalt = lazy1.getAttribute("alt");
 let shop = document.querySelector('.shop');
 shop.classList.add(lazyalt);

    console.log(lazyalt)
```